# identifying duplicate values in linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, duplicates

I want to identify which ones and how many values are duplicate in a linked list that was user's input. And this is the code I wrote for it:

```
int count;
int compare, compare2;

    for (p = first; p != NULL; p = p->next){
         compare = p->num;
        for (j = first; j != NULL; j = j->next){
            if (compare == j->num){
                compare2 = j->num;
                 count++;
            }
        }
        if (count > 1){
            cout << "There are at least 2 identical values of: " << compare2 << " that repeat for: " << count << "times" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Basically the idea of it was that I take the first element in the first loop and compare it to all the elements in the second loop and count if there are cases of them being similar, and print the result after - then I take next element and so on.

However the output is all the elements and it doesn't count correctly either. I'm just lost at how to adjust it.

I tried using the same p variable in both loops as it is the same list I want to loop, but then the .exe failed as soon as I'd finished input.

I saw a few examples around where there was function for deleting duplicate values, but the comparison part run through with while loop, and I'm just wondering - what am I doing wrong on this one?!

Comment: What about stepping through your code with a debugger line by line, to get what's actually going wrong with it?

Comment: You could easily do this with a `std::map<int, int>` instead of writing an O(n^2) loop.

Comment: You didn't initialize `count` to 0.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for quick replies. I'm reluctant to use std::map, because I don't understand it well enough yet and I do want to understand the error I'm already making. As for count not being initialized - when I did that on my original code the .exe failed before user input could be finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic is flawed since both `p` and `j` iterate over the entire list. When `p == j`, the values are bound to match.

Change the block

```
        if (compare == j->num){
            compare2 = j->num;
             count++;
        }
```

to

```
        if (p != j && compare == j->num){
            compare2 = j->num;
             count++;
        }
```

Also, you don't need the line

```
            compare2 = j->num;
```

since `compare2` will be equal to `compare`.

You can reduce the number of tests by changing the inner for loop a bit. Then, you won't need the `p != j` bit either.

```
    for (j = p->next; j != NULL; j = j->next){
        if (compare == j->num){
             count++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Your advice really fixes some of the issues, however the output is still glitchy - it either outputs the repeated value for all the times there was a loop, or (2nd fix) it just prints out all the values saying they repeated at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Your *O(N*N)* approach :

```
// Pick an element
for (p = first; p != NULL && p->next !=NULL ; p = p->next)
{   // Compare it with remaining elements
    for (j = p->next ; j != NULL; j = j->next)
    {  
       if ( p->num == j->num)
       {        
          count++;
       }
    if( cout > 1 )
    {
       std::cout << p->num << " occurs "<< count << times << '\n' ;
    }
}
```

Its better to use a HashMap to solve this is *O(N)* time with *N* extra space

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> m ;
for( p = first; p != NULL ; p = p->next )
{
   m[ p->num ]++;
}
for (const auto &pair : m ) 
{
    if( pair.second > 1 )
      std::cout << pair.first << ": " << pair.second << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't exclude element you compare to (`compare`). So for every element it found at least one duplicate - itself!
Try to compare element in inner loop only followed by current (`p`).

Comment: I applied the second if statement to fix that. Like - count is bound to be at least 1 anyway as it checks itself, but if it's larger the value repeats later in the list. That however didn't work exactly as intended.

Comment: @Elsa Add `count = 0;` just before `compare = p->num;`

Comment: Omg, yes! Now it works! With your advice and @R-Sahu it finally completely works! Thank you!! I'm so sorry, I can't upvote yet, you both helped immensely :)